# In dockerfile how can I use OS specific commands

Tags: dockerfile

Link: https://docs.docker.com/linux/step_four/

While creating our own image, the Step 9 has contents of Dockerfile,

`FROM docker/whalesay:latest
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes
CMD /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay`

But `apt-get` is an OS specific command isnt it?
How can I just assume the container(stripped down version of linux) will have apt-get to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which commands (in this case, which package manager) you can use depends on what "base" image is used for an image.

In this case, the docker/whalesay image is based on Ubuntu 14.04. The Dockerfile that's used to build this image can be seen on Docker Hub; https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/whalesay/

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# install cowsay, and move the "default.cow" out of the way so we can overwrite it with "docker.cow"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cowsay --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && mv /usr/share/cowsay/cows/default.cow /usr/share/cowsay/cows/orig-default.cow

# "cowsay" installs to /usr/games
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/games

COPY docker.cow /usr/share/cowsay/cows/
RUN ln -sv /usr/share/cowsay/cows/docker.cow /usr/share/cowsay/cows/default.cow

CMD ["cowboy"]
```

Ubuntu and Debian are a popular choice as a base image, and most official images are base on Debian, but you can also find images based on, for example, CentOS; https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/mariadb/

#### Minimal distro's

Images based on Ubuntu and CentOS are relatively large. Most of the time, this is not a problem, because layers can be shared between images, so all images that are based on the same version of (e.g.) Ubuntu, don't need to download those layers again.

Docker image generally are used for a single service, many parts of Linux are not required at all, so why include them to start with? For this reason, you'll see more and more images that are based on a *minimal* distribution, such as [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/).

For example, [the official Redis image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/) is now also available in an Alpine variant. It's still the same Redis, and has the same features, but the size difference compared to the Debian-based version is huge;

```
REPOSITORY  TAG        IMAGE ID       CREATED      SIZE
redis       3-alpine   56ddc4d21480   6 days ago   15.95 MB
redis       3          d4deec2c521c   12 days ago  151.3 MB
```

#### Binary-only images

Some images don't even need a Linux base at all; if a binary is statically compiled, it's possible to create an image that contains *just the binary itself*. For example, the [Hello World](https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world/) image contains just a binary and the total size of that image is 960 bytes.